# object undefined javascript handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

This works fine and returns the string which I pass to the function

```
    Handlebars.registerHelper('date', function (strng) {        
    return strng;
    });
```

This tells me strng is undefined..

```
    Handlebars.registerHelper('date', function (strng) {       
    return strng.substring(1,7);
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

More context:

I am adding this to handlebars.js file.

I am invoking it with the following template:

`Date Added: <b>{{{date TriageRecord.DateAdded}}}</b> <br />`

The first piece of code I added returns the string back to the template just fine.  When I add strng.substring(1,7) it errors out.

Documentation: [Here](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html)

Comment: Not enough info, we need some context here.

Comment: Something else is going on, that stuff works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ALJRw/